# Get "geometry column" error when importing my csv file on Google Earth Engine through asset tab

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, geometry, csv, error

I want to localize my plant specimens on Google Earth Engine map by importing a CSV file with two columns, including longitude and latitude, which belong to Quebec province, Canada. After I select my CSV file, I set all information, such as CRS, on the default setting (but I don't know what should I write in the "Primary geometry column"). Then I click on the upload button. When I select my CSV file on the "asset' tab, I see this error "the table may not have valid geometries" in the left-side corner. After importing the data, two types of errors are showing up in the "tasks" tab;

1. Error: Cannot overwrite asset 'projects/ee-mobina70gholamhosseini/assets/data'. (Error code: 3)
2. Error: No such geometry column 'geometry' exists to set as primary. (Error code: 3)

What's wrong with my CSV file, and what information should I add to geolocalize my specimens on Google Earth Engine? I have attached the screenshot of the error that appears on the asset tab as well as a few lines of my CSV file.

```
long,lat
-73.194,45.5626
-73.312,45.5754
-73.911498,45.612622
-73.551226,45.937234
-73.427248,45.92802
-73.556763,45.769156
-70.8,46.65
-73.566667,45.95
-73.6,45.85
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Cannot overwrite asset 'projects/ee-mobina70gholamhosseini/assets/data'. (Error code: 3)

You will need to delete the existing asset, or upload the new one with a different Asset ID.

> I don't know what should I write in the "Primary geometry column"

You have separate columns for latitude and longitude, so you should leave “Primary geometry column” blank, then put the name of your longitude column in “X column” and the name of your latitude column in “Y column”.

In the sample data you have provided, the header is `long,lat` so you should write `long` in **X column** and `lat` in **Y column**.

I did this and imported your data successfully:

[image]

[image]